# Counting postcodes in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook that gathers information from learners including their postcodes. I want to count how many people are coming from each postcode but I don't know which postcodes to expect. Is there a way of tallying text in cells when you don't know if new post codes will be added?

Comment: Sounds to me like you can use a pivot table on the post codes, and a count of those post codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort the data then you could use Data, Subtotal and use "at each change in postcode", "use function COUNT"

Answer (score -1):

Pivot tables or even filtering if you have some time on your hands

Comment: this is not a question. can you explain more?